# How to update data table on data change highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a pie chart that I'm updating dynamically on button click using the code below.

On Button click

```
   $("#myChart").highcharts().series[0].setData($.extend(true, [], data1))
```

I'm using keys to populate the data table.

```
 keys: ['Count','Value'],
```

This works fine and updates the chart but I also have export data table enabled in export menu but that data table doesn't update. It remains the same on all successive button clicks.

How can I update the data table with button click to show data for new data.

here is a fiddle but it doesn't really use buttons but just to give you an idea of my chart : https://jsfiddle.net/mewohraz/1/

Update: The solution below works but I had to comment out this piece of code that I'm using to toggle the viewData table. It allows me to close the table if you click on viewData again. How do I get to work it with chart.viewData()?

```
Highcharts.Chart.prototype.viewData = function () {
    if (!this.insertedTable) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'highcharts-data-table';
        // Insert after the chart container
        this.renderTo.parentNode.insertBefore(div, this.renderTo.nextSibling);
        div.innerHTML = this.getTable();
        this.insertedTable = true;
        div.id = this.container.id + '-data-table';
    }
    else {
        $('#' + this.container.id + '-data-table').toggle();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `viewData` internal method to refresh the data table:

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {
    var data1 = [...];

    chart.series[0].setData(data1);
    chart.viewData();
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ahowu9tm/

Comment: Hey check the update in my post. It works but I had to comment out that piece of code otherwise it doesn't work. I need that code since I need to close the table too.

Comment: Hi @Caesar Tex, You can add some argument to the function, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gLsuvb5m/

Comment: I have a similar issue just followed the Live Demo in the answer but I cant see it working for me. Has the code been updated since? I cant refresh the data table. chart.viewData(); doesnt seem to be working

Comment: Hi @RA19, Could you provide an example? The jsfiddle from the above answer seems to work correctly.

Comment: Weird its working now! - dont know why it wasnt before